# How to get full information about MACRO which is used in configure.ac

Tags: linux, makefile, autotools

I am a beginner of linux, now I study the auto tool for GNU app.

I get the autoconf documentation from gnu web site.

But the macro for configure.ac is not enough for me.

Is there any place that provides the full info about that ? the macro like `AC_PROG_LIBTOOL`, and `AC_RPOG_RANLIB`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best place for documentation on the two macros you mention is `info libtool` and `info autoconf`.  Note that `AC_PROG_LIBTOOL` is deprecated and should be replaced with `LT_INIT`.  For all the gory details, see the file `$( aclocal --print )/libtool.m4`.  (That is, look for the file named `libtool.m4` in the directory path `aclocal` looks in.)